# Issue with box-shadow :before :after and long Website

Tags: css

I'm trying to adapt [following style](http://jsfiddle.net/YJnRS/1/) on a div (filled with content) on my site. The problem is, that as the content gets bigger (long texts, many pictures, etc) -and as a result, the div gets longer- at some point that happens: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zZk2p/1/) (scroll to the bottom).

If I change the top-attribute of the :after & :before to `top:99%`, that problem disappears at the very long divs, but at the same time, the shadow disappears at relatively short div's.

I don't really hav an idea how to solve this. Maybe you know a fix or workaround.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `top` property? Just remove it and add height to it. For example,

`height:100px` or `height:5%`

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/zZk2p/2/)

Comment: Ok, that was suprisingly easy. I tried something like this before, but for some reason it didn't work out for me. Most probably I forgot something. Thanks!